# DataTable.ReadXML Failing to Read XML from My.Settings VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, datatable

I have a piece of software whereby I 'add' documents to a `DataTable` and then save that information to a My.Settings string using `DataTable.WriteXML` so that the next time the software is launched the Load Event uses the `DataTable.ReadXML` method to then repopulate the `DataTable`.

I have had an assistant populate the datatable using the 'form' I have created so that it saves me the long laborious task of moving the files and file names myself.

I have then a `TextBox` that gives me the 'value' of the My.Settings.DataTable value so that I can then input this into my 'test' environment to use the values he has updated to debug.

I copy and paste the text into the My.Settings.DataTable inside Visual Studio but when my Form loads and the `DataTable.ReadXML` method is used it fails complaining with:

```
'<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character
```

HOWEVER I understand this is because within the App.Config file it doesn't like reading '<' '>' etc.

I can confirm the App.Config file states these as < and > so I don't understand how the error is coming up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have 171 reputation. You shoul now how to ask a question by now. Please re read this [ask] .. and this .. [mcve]